# How to pull my second last or n'th last push

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

When I run `git log`, I see:

```
commit d0fa4410393w92ce6ede2ea26fa2fb74z2e5f1bz (HEAD -> notificationControls, origin/notificationControls)
Author: stufezic-dev <ninjahero@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 19 12:32:45 2020 +0545

    lockscreen controls working, notification updates yet to fix

commit 2e11d85350a741d6992875e949a0a77abbeb8fde (mainadjust, commitBranch)
Author: stufezic-dev <ninjahero@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 15 23:30:27 2020 +0545

    notification and lockscreen controls using mediaSession: initiated  
  
commit 2e11d85350a741d6992875e949a0a77abbeb8fde (mainadjust, commitBranch)
Author: stufezic-dev <ninjahero@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 14 23:30:27 2020 +0545

    notification and lockscreen controls using mediaSession: initiated  
  
...
```

How do I pull the second last or the third last commit, instead of the latest commit? I had only known of 1 command: `git pull master origin`, and I'm thinking of how to I pull any commit instead of the latest commit.

Comment: By command `git pull origin master` you pull all the commits that are present on the master branch of origin remote to your current local banch, now what you want? to get commits till second last and skip the latest commit?

Comment: That's actually what `git log` says? Did you really create the same commit twice exactly 24 hours apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull origin master` is equivalent to `git fetch origin`, followed by `git merge origin/master`.

If you want to merge something else than `origin/master` in your branch (say : the third commit before `origin/master`), use `git fetch` instead of `git pull` :

```
git fetch

# inspect the history
git log --graph origin/master HEAD

# merge whatever commit you want into your branch
git merge eacf32
```